# Maintain current button pagination highlighted

Tags: css, reactjs, pagination

I'm working on a React app and only CSS, and I'm trying to get my pagination button to be selected in a different color when changing the page, so that the current page remains selected.

But I am not getting it even with other questions that I have already checked.

The button changes color when I click on it, but it doesn't stay on.

My pagination and CSS would look like this:

```
    <div className={style.Pagination_numbers}>
      <ul className={style.Pagination__ul}>
        {pageNumbers?.map((number) => {
          return (
            //loop for the pageNumbers
          <li className={style.list}>
            <button onClick={() => pagination(number)}>{number}</button>
          </li>)
          })}
      </ul>
      <button className={style.backButton} onClick={prevPage}>Back</button>
      <button className={style.advanceButton} onClick={nextPage}>Next</button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.list > button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin: 5px;
    bottom: 19px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: 200;
    left: 135px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000a2;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.list > button:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.list > button:active {
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(71, 117, 218);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your button style to remain different (here similar to your `:active` pseudo-class) once the page is selected.

Unfortunately, CSS alone will not be enough: it could only style based on some immediate events (like `:hover` or `:active`) or to some extent based on navigation history (with [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) pseudo-class), but that would match *all* previously visited pages, not just the current one.

To achieve the style on the *currently selected page only*, you need a [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to store the information of the currently selected page. Then, based on that state, you can conditionally apply a style on a particular page button (the one corresponding to the current page), e.g. using a class: (below snippet assumes you use React Functional Components with hooks)

```
function App() {
  const pageNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  // State to store the currently selected page
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(null);

  function pagination(number) {
    // Record the selected page in state
    setPage(number);
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {pageNumbers?.map((number) => (
        //loop for the pageNumbers
        <li className="list">
          <button
            onClick={() => pagination(number)}
            // Apply an "active" class
            // if page is selected
            className={number === page ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {number}
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

```css
.list > button:active,
/* Also select button with "active" class */
.list > button.active {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(71, 117, 218);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ghybs/pen/gOjLgxR